# ngroups in groupby object not matching nunique() in same column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame consisting of Ids and Serial Numbers. I want to create a new DataFrame with the Ids as index and the serial numbers as column values and zero padding where the length are not equal.

My problem is that when I try to group by id the number of groups in my groupby("id")-object does not match the number of nunique("id") values which is counter intuitive. For every example I tried using smaller DateFrames the numbers match. Any suggestions why?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data example (real df is shape(188225, 2)
hu = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ['1','12','123','1234','12345'], 
                   'Serial':['A','AB','ABC','ABC','ABC']},
                    dtype = 'category') 

max_len = df.groupby('Id')['Serial'].size().max() # Find the max length 

grouped = df.groupby('Id') 

from io import StringIO
from csv import writer

output = StringIO()
csv_writer = writer(output)

for key, vals in grouped.groups.items():
    # Vector of serials with 0 padding matching so max_len = | [a, b, c, 0, 0, 0...]|
    csv_writer.writerow(np.append(np.append(key, vals.values), np.array([0] * (max_len - len(vals)))))

    output.seek(0) #goes to the start of the IO file
    dfdiscrete = pd.read_csv(output,
                             header=None,
                             index_col=0,
                             dtype=str)

print("\Discrete Serials:", len(grouped.groups), "nunique ids", hu['Id'].nunique())
```

I expect the these two to be:
`Shape discrete devices: (29840, 50) nunique citizen ids 29840`,
but the actual output is 
`Shape discrete devices: (56674, 50) nunique citizen ids 29840`

Comment: as far a I remember nunique does not consider null values, while groupby does, use .count() to check

Comment: @EzerK, there are no null values so hu[CitizenId].count() equals len(hu[CitizenId])

Comment: Couldn't find the problem, if you post a minimal set of data causing the error, if possible, we might be able to help you.

Comment: Above code does not run

Comment: @RichAndrews i converted keys to strings now and its running.

Comment: @EzerK - That is the problem. Every smaller dataset i tested it against does not have this problem

Comment: The solution is to do grouped = df.groupby('Id', observed=True). 
The groupby function auto completes the categorical variables and thus makes groupes without any serials.